# How to compare multiple checkboxlist values in LINQ like IN clause SQL

Tags: c#, linq

Here in this code 'chklstDepartment' is having multiple values but is displaying but is binding data for the first selected item only.
How can I get data binded for all the selected checkboxlist values?

```
List<LessonLearnDetails> objLessonDetails = objLessonDashboard.getLessonLearntDetails();
var searchData = objLessonDetails
    .Where(i => ddlAsset.SelectedValue == "0" ||
                i._Asset.AssetID == ddlAsset.SelectedValue)
    .Where(i => ddlAuditType.SelectedValue == "0" ||
                i._Audit.AuditTypeID == ddlAuditType.SelectedValue)
    .Where(i => chklstDepartment.SelectedValue == "0" ||
                i._Department.DepartmentID == chklstDepartment.SelectedValue)
    .Where(i => ddlStartYear.SelectedItem.Text == "--Select All--" ||
                i._Year.StartYear == ddlStartYear.SelectedItem.Text)
    .Where(i => ddlEndYear.SelectedItem.Text == "--Select All--" ||
                i._Year.EndYear == ddlEndYear.SelectedItem.Text)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
BindGrid(searchData);
```

I have also used a function for storing checked values and passed that values using chklstDepartment.Contains() but it returning 0.

```
for (int i = 0; i < chklstDepartment.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (chklstDepartment.Items[i].Selected)
    {
        chbstr += chklstDepartment.Items[i].Value + ",";
        count++;
        //if(count > 1)
    }
    var data = new string[] {chbstr};
}
chbstr = chbstr == string.Empty ? "0" : chbstr;
//chbstr = chklstDepartment.SelectedValue;
//chbstr = chbstr.Split(',').ToString();
return chbstr;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't return a string but an enumerable of strings. You could alter your where statement.

Something like:

```
.Where(i => (chklstDepartment.SelectedValue == "0")
         || (chklstDepartment.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                   .Where(item => item.Selected)
                                   .Select(item => item.Value)
                                   .Contains(i._Department.DepartmentID)))
```

if `DepartmentID` is an `int`, you can try this:

```
.Where(i => (chklstDepartment.SelectedValue == "0")
         || (chklstDepartment.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                   .Where(item => item.Selected)
                                   .Select(item => Convert.ToInt32(item.Value))
                                   .Contains(i._Department.DepartmentID)))
```

---

You might consider caching the selection:

```
var selectedIds = chklstDepartment.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                                        .Where(item => item.Selected)
                                        .Select(item => Convert.ToInt32(item.Value))
                                        .ToArray(); // or ToList() or HashSet

.Where(i => (chklstDepartment.SelectedValue == "0")
         || (selectedIds.Contains(i._Department.DepartmentID)))
```

Comment: It is throwing an error.
Its doesn't contain a definition for 'Where'...

Comment: It's probably i forgot the `.Value`.. i updated it. This is typed in stackoverflow, so might contains minor errors. It's all about the idea..

Comment: chklstDepartment.Items.Where(item => item.Value)

Here I'm getting error...

Comment: I've added the `Cast<>()`

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeroen van Langen for the help. I was stucked from the past few hours on this.
Thanks.
It is working fine.

Comment: Great! Good luck on the next challenges.

Comment: For (chklstDepartment.SelectedValue == "0") it is not working.